# Using REM in chrome, can't reproduce error

Tags: css, google-chrome, font-size

As the title says, I'm experimenting using REMS with a px fall back for older browsers on all elements of the page, not just fonts.  The test website is: test.glow-sticks.org

Apologies if any of the terminology below is incorrect, I'm far from being an expert!

On resolutions over 1024 the font-size using the (html in css) is set at 62.5%, simply so 1rem = 10px, on this resolution I've got the default font to 1.4rem / 14px

On resolutions over 1680 the html css is set at 71.4%, by setting this percentage the fonts go from 14px to 16px and of course all of the elements increase by the same percentage, which is pretty cool and seems to keep everything in perfect sync.

On my computer this seems to work perfectly, as it does on many other of my test platforms that I've been using.  However my web developer seems to be running into a problem on her machine, but only in chrome. (firefox and IE are not affected)

On her machine, when she drops her resolution down to 1024 (from her native 1920) resolution the website is loading with horizontal scroll bars, when on my machine it fits fine on 1024.
It gets more interesting when using the chrome inspection element tool.  I have been checking one DIV in particular Div id=wholepage, when viewing on 1024 screen it should be 960px wide and when viewing on 1680+ it should be 1097px wide.

However on her Chrome, the div=wholepage is showing 1152px on the 1024 resolution and also 1152px on her native 1920 resolution.

I have noticed on my version of Chrome, I have to set the font-size to 75% to reproduce the same.  It seems as if no matter what I set the font-size to the wholepage div still wants to be 1152px.  I even tried 10%, which quite rightly on my chrome, made everything tiny, however on her machine nothing changes.  The only thing that does change is the font-size does say 10%, but it's as if it's not being respected and it's being over-ridden by some 75% minimum.

Can anyone reproduce this please?

The only fix she can come up with is using higher percentages like 90% and 103% which offers the same increase as 62.5 and 71.4, however it seemed much nicer to keep it so 1 rem = 10px, which is why I want to keep this 62.5 as the base.

Comment: You want us to visit an untrusted SSL website?

Comment: no you don't have to, I know it looks bad, but I was just testing the https for something else a while back and haven't switched it back yet.

Comment: I'm encountering the same weird thing now on one of the windows computers with Chrome 74!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's OK, I've been able to reproduce the error by setting chrome minimum-font-size to 12px or higher.  In my settings it was set as 6px, which is why everything loaded fine on my version.

16px being the default size for chrome and 12px probably being the default minimum font size for chrome explains why my web developer was only being able to go as low as 75% as a font-size.  I've also noticed -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; no longer works, which is understandable!

Comment: How do you set chrome minimum-font-size?

Comment: Still an issue in 2019: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56404524/rem-units-do-not-affect-divs-in-chrome :/