# rem units do not affect DIVs in Chrome - side-effect of minimum font size setting

Tags: css, google-chrome, font-size

I've stumbled upon a very bizarre case, where `rem` units were not affecting `DIV`s (and potentially all other block elements), but were still effective against text (and I suspect all other inline elements). This was happening on one Windows computer only and only in Chrome 74. On all other platforms (Linux, Mac OS X) and other browses (even legacy Safari and in Canary, which is at Chrome 76 at the moment it worked as expected).

I had no chance to test it extensively, but I've witnessed it myself and wasn't able to detect the source of the problem. I tried it in incognito mode as well, so no cache or third party extensions should have affected it.

Has anyone encountered it or has any solution? I've tested https://youtube.com/tv (which is built with `rems`) on the very same computer and it scaled properly. The only difference between my site and YouTubes is that I set the `fontSize` on the root element in pixels rather than in percents.

Any ideas?

```js
const updateRatio = () => {
  const ratio = Math.min(window.innerWidth / 640, window.innerHeight / 480);
  document.querySelector(":root").style.fontSize = `${ratio}px`;
};
window.addEventListener("resize", updateRatio);
updateRatio();
```

```css
#app {
  border: 2px dashed red;
  width: 320rem;
  height: 240rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-resonance-dn1bn. To see the effect, resize the panel with the dashed red box.

Comment: Would you create a Stack Snippet to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: Updated with the code sandbox.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not sufficient to re-open the question. Questions need to be primarily self-contained here, so that the breakage or modification of an external link does not affect the readability of the question. If you've managed to acquire 7K in rep without having encountered this rule before, then that's impressive/unfortunate depending on your perspective `;-)`.

Comment: Some examples cannot work in Stack Snippet. Thus - Codesandbox. Included it though.

Comment: You're not required to use a Stack Snippet. If Stack Snippets don't work, don't use it. However, you are required to keep the MCVE in the question - but there's no requirement to have it runnable straight from the question

Comment: Thanks @Zoe, casting a reopen vote also. (jayarjo, if you want to convert the Stack Snippet to ordinary code blocks, that is fine - as long as the code remains in the post in some fashion).

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue you describe in Chrome 74 on Windows 10. The code functions the same in Chrome 74 as it does in Firefox. I've tried using both the snippet in the question and the codesandbox.io code.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. I can reproduce it on a single PC only.

Comment: You could try installing VirtualBox on the problem PC, installing a free Windows virtual machine, and installing Chrome on it. If that works then I would ignore the problem as unreproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Chrome has this setting - "Minimum font size" (chrome://settings/fonts?search=minimum). So if you manage to make the reference `fontSize` smaller than what is set there, whole `rem` logic will break.

Here's how it was set in the problematic Chrome.

[image]